# spider 2.2.2 несовместимость версий

Tags: flutter

```
Resolving dependencies...
Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on path 1.8.0 and spider >=2.2.0 depends on path ^1.8.1, flutter_test from sdk is incompatible with spider >=2.2.0.
So, because moviedb depends on both spider ^2.2.1 and flutter_test from sdk, version solving failed.
pub finished with exit code 1
exit code 1
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' 

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
 
  flutter_secure_storage: ^5.0.2
  pedantic: ^1.11.1
  spider: ^2.2.0

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^1.0.4

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

Answer (score 0):

решено:

#dart pub upgrade --null-safety

Changed 3 constraints in pubspec.yaml:

spider: ^2.2.2 -> ^2.1.0

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2 -> ^1.0.4

flutter_lints: ^1.0.0 -> ^1.0.4